# Как прижать блоки в краю?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы блоки features-block по правой и левой  стороне упирались в блок content и при этом сами блоки features-block остались такими,как прежде?

Сам сайт c96180og.beget.tech

Код jsfiddle.net/z1awxcuj/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте эти стили

```
.features-block {
    ...
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    width: calc(100%/3 - 40px);
}
```

```
.features-slider {
    ...
    justify-content: space-between;
    ...
}
```